# thttpd memory usage

Tags: memory, thttpd

I have a thttpd server running on an ARM box, and I use it to serve images through a cgi.

What I observe is with each image served, the amount of free memory is lower, and in the
psoutput, the VSZ column grow for thttpd.

At some point thttpd gives me an error 500 when asng for the CGI, and the log says "unable to fork"

The amount of memory the vsz is growing is about the size of the image served. Is thttpd doing some kind of caching, but is not able to reclaim memory when forking ? Memory leaking ?

How can I disable this caching behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two directives that allows you to limit the mmap cache of thttpd, they are [DESIRED_MAX_MAPPED_FILES](http://www.acme.com/software/thttpd/options.html#DESIRED_MAX_MAPPED_FILES) and [DESIRED_MAX_MAPPED_BYTES](http://www.acme.com/software/thttpd/options.html#DESIRED_MAX_MAPPED_BYTES).